# Using callbacks/anonymous functions/delegates?

Tags: c#

I have the following functions in my class:

```
public void RenderStylePrefabs()
{
    foreach (Renderer renderer in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<AvatarStyle>().prefabs.ContainsValue(renderer.name))
        {
            renderer.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

public void UnrenderAllPrefabs()
{
    foreach (Renderer renderer in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        renderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Notice how they both use the same foreach loop.

How can I turn this into something like:

```
public void RenderStylePrefabs()
{
    RenderLoop({
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<AvatarStyle>().prefabs.ContainsValue(renderer.name))
        {
            renderer.enabled = true;
        }
    });
}

public void UnrenderAllPrefabs()
{
    RenderLoop({
        renderer.enabled = false;
    });
}

private void RenderLoop(doStuff)
{
    foreach (Renderer renderer in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how to do this properly. I was reading on delegates and stuff but its kind of confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the with the idea to use delegates.

The `RenderLoop()` method should look like:

```
private void RenderLoop(Action<Renderer> doStuff)
{
    foreach (Renderer renderer in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        doStuff(renderer);
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it from your other methods like (change accordingly):

```
RenderLoop((renderer) => renderer.enabled = true);
```

The parentheses around `renderer` are optional in this case, but required if the delegate has more than one parameter.